# Is there a way to turn lazy-loading off?

Tags: angular, webpack, lazy-loading

I have a large angular 8 application with a custom webpack build that I have started to enable lazy-loading for and it is working great. My question is...is there a way to turn lazy loading off app-wide?

I know that in order to eagerly load my angular modules I just need to import them in the root module but I am hoping for a way to achieve the same thing without having to go through all of our modules manually. Is there a webpack setting that will eagerly load all chunks for example?

Any feedback is greatly appreciated and let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try PreloadAllModules

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
```

However, this does not turn off lazy loading like you wanted but preload all the modules so you don't load them on demand (lazy loading).